# Manually triggering the styling on a jQuery mobile select list

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm building a select list with an Ajax call that is triggered when another select list is changed.

The page loads correctly with the jQuery styling, but when I replace my ajax container with the new div I can't get jQuery mobile to format it.  This means that it reverts to the native select list format.

I have tried what is suggested in the [JQM documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4/docs/forms/forms-selects.html):

```
var myselect = $("select#foo");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

but that does not work.  My page initially loads with this:

```
<div id="ajax-destination">
     <select id="destinationAirport" data-native-menu="false">
      <option value="-- Please Select --" data-placeholder="true">-- Please Select --</option>
     </select>
```

and this is my jQuery code wrapped in the change function of the other select list.

```
$('#ajax-destination').empty();
$.post(url, { departureAirport : departureAirport }, function(data) {
    $('#ajax-destination').append(data);
var myselect = $("#destinationAirport");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 1;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
});
```

The only other way I can think to do this is to return a JSON array via Ajax and use that to add the options to the select list, but I would prefer to just send formatted HTML because it's simpler to follow.

Comment: you could try myselect.trigger('create');

Comment: Hi Phil,  can you make that an answer so I can accept it?  The full solution was to: $.post(url, { departureAirport : departureAirport }, function(data) {
     $('#ajax-destination').append(data).trigger( "create" );
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `myselect.selectmenu("refresh");` or `myselect.selectmenu("refresh",true);` doesn't work you can always refresh the page using

```
you could try myselect.trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 2):

@Andy :

myselect.selectmenu("refresh"); will refresh the select box and where as 
***myselect.selectmenu('refresh', true)***; will rebuild the select menu.It may helps you out.  Check this link once http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-add-items-and-refresh-the-select-menu-in-jquery-mobile